# jQuery: $.post doesn't get 200 response from server inside click event

Tags: jquery, post

Here is my $.post call:

```
$.post('<?php echo site_url('channel_partners/notify_uls/collateral'); ?>',
            {nameUrl: 'test'},
                function(data) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
        );
```

This works fine in the document.ready part of the jQuery call.  But if I put it inside a click event, it no longer posts.  The call is shown in red in Firebug and there is no "200 OK" beside it any longer.  Also, the data is not passed.

Here is my click event:

```
$(function() {
    $('#Letter, #Postcard').click(function() {
            var nameUrl = <?php echo '"' . $cp_name_and_url->name_url . '"'; ?>;
            var language = <?php echo '"' . $lang . '"'; ?>;
            var collat = this.id;
             $.post('<?php echo site_url('channel_partners/notify_uls/collateral'); ?>',
                 {nameUrl: 'test'},
                    function(data) {
                        // Do nothing
                    }
            );

    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see an error in Firebug?

Comment: Yes, the post call is in red.  But there is no error message

Comment: I tried using $.ajax to get a response from the server and the message that came back was just "error".

Comment: Check the response in Firebug, there should be an error.

Comment: try once by commenting first three line of assigning value to variable, is it works or not?

Comment: There is no error. Just the script call in red and a red x in a circle

Comment: Hardik-- I eliminated the variables as part of the problem.  I commented out the lines and I still have the same issue.  The post works outside the click event but not inside it.

Comment: the post is being doing for the correct url?

Comment: Yes.  The post call works fine if I put it above the click event.

Comment: have you tried to remove all PHP variables and put each one as statics variables to test?

Answer (score 0):

Try following, may be it works!

```
...
//var nameUrl = <?php echo '"' . $cp_name_and_url->name_url . '"'; ?>;
var nameUrlValue = <?php echo '"' . $cp_name_and_url->name_url . '"'; ?>;
...
//{nameUrl: 'test'},
{nameUrl: nameUrlValue},
...
```

Comment: This has something to do with the nature of click events and post.  I just don't know what.

Comment: could you please right click on that red error and open in new tab, let us know what error you are getting?

Comment: `#Letter, #Postcard` are anchor tag?
if it is then try to modify your code to preventDefault event of anchor tag

Comment: I solved it.  The link I was clicking on was also downloading a file through the browser.  On a regular link, the script works fine.